# How to parse this date string in pyspark using new time parser policy?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have been trying to parse a date string in pyspark. But, I found that I can only parse using LEGACY policy, how can we parse the following string using the newer default policy?

```py
spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy")
spark.sql("SELECT to_date('2020-09-20 Sun', 'yyyy-MM-dd E') AS Parsed").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest spark version as of now, you don't need to use `dd` even for two-digit days, `d` suffices for 2 digit days as well.

The following code would work

```
spark.sql("SELECT to_date('2020-09-20 Sun', 'yyyy-MM-d E') AS Parsed").show()
```

EDIT: Removed code for unsetting legacy time parser policy

Comment: This gives: SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.DATETIME_PATTERN_RECOGNITION] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0: ( I have pyspark 3.3)

Comment: Remove any `spark.conf` for legacy and try again in a new session.